# Selectively Follow Redirects in Go

Tags: go

I'm trying to write a twitter reader that resolves the final URLs of link shorteners etc, but gives me a URL along the way for a list of manually defined host patterns. The reason to do this is that i don't want to end up with the paywall URL but the one before.

As far as i can tell the way to do this is write my own client based on the default `RoundTripper` because returning an error from a custom `CheckRedirect` function aborts the client without yielding a response.

Is there a way to use the default `client` and record a list of URLs/specific URL from a custom `checkRedirect` function?

Comment: Waiting a few days if anyone comes up with a clever wrapper or manipulating the `Request´, otherwise feel free to add as answer then.

Comment: @Bruno doing it by extending the default roundtripper is no biggie, are you interested in that? I did something similar when implementing an http cache.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer Oh yes, would be highly appreciated. 

New to Go so my impression was that i'D have to rewrite either http://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go#L302 or https://github.com/pkulak/simpletransport/blob/master/simpletransport/simple_transport.go to achieve this, but an example of how to achieve by simple extension would be like Birthday & New Years rolle d into one!

Comment: @Bruno okay I'll try, but I might have missed something in your question and it is more complicated than I thought.

Comment: @Bruno: Can you clarify what you want? The documentation specifically says `If CheckRedirect returns an error, the Client's Get method returns both the previous Response and CheckRedirect's error`. You should have the response available.

Comment: @JimB If I understand correctly, what OP wants is the final URL for some domains, and the shortened URL for others, but the final data for all of them.

Comment: Don't sure I clear understand what you want to achieve, but you have *Request (reference) as argument in CheckRedirect(req *Request, via []*Request) func. So you can   easily change Request, say redirect to your own Request.URL or something instead of issuing an error.

Comment: Much appreciated, clarified the question a bit (hopefully):

In the case of `on.ft.com/14pQBYE` i want to record `http://www.ft.com/intl/cms/s/701a3c36-95be-11e4-a390-00144feabdc0.html` instead of the longer paywall URL.

Doing it by recording a specific step in the redirect chain, eg if the hostname matches a specific string, seems more reliable/generic that trying to fiddle with final URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client request *will* actually still return the last valid `Response` in cases where your custom `CheckResponse` yields an error (As mentioned in the comments).

http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Client

> If CheckRedirect returns an error, the Client's Get method returns both the previous Response and CheckRedirect's error (wrapped in a url.Error) instead of issuing the Request req.

If you maintain a list of "known" paywall-urls, you can abort the paywall-redirect in your `CheckResponse` with a custom `error` type (`Paywalled` in the example below). 
Your error handling code later has to consider that error type as a special (non-erroneous) case.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
)

var Paywalled = errors.New("next redirect would hit a paywall")

var badHosts = map[string]error{
    "registration.ft.com": Paywalled,
}

var client = &http.Client{
    CheckRedirect: func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
        // N.B.: when used in production, also check for redirect loops
        return badHosts[req.URL.Host]
    },
}

func main() {
    resp, err := client.Get("http://on.ft.com/14pQBYE")
    // ignore non-nil err if it's a `Paywalled` wrapped in url.Error
    if e, ok := err.(*url.Error); (ok && e.Err != Paywalled) || (!ok && err != nil) {
        fmt.Println("error: ", err)
        return
    }   
    resp.Body.Close()
    fmt.Println(resp.Request.URL)
}
```