# how to get the redirect url instead of page content in golang?

Tags: http, redirect, go

I am sending a request to server but it is returning a web page. Is there a way to get the url of the web page instead?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://www.google.com", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    client := new(http.Client)
    response, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body))
}
```

Comment: possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24518945/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865691/, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27814942/

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to check for redirect and stop(capture) them. If you capture a redirection then you can get the redirect URL (to which redirection was happening) using location method of response struct.

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://www.google.com", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    client := new(http.Client)
    client.CheckRedirect = func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
        return errors.New("Redirect")
    }

    response, err := client.Do(req)
    if response != nil && response.StatusCode == http.StatusFound { //status code 302
        fmt.Println(response.Location())
    } else { // handle err or response == nil 
        fmt.Printf("rsp: %+v, err: %v\n", response, err)
    }
}
```

Comment: `response.StatusCode` triggers an error: `panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x10 pc=0x647069]`

Comment: @Thykof The if logic is wrong, I've fixed it