# How to get a hold of the first HTTP (redirect) response?

Tags: http, go

I developed a code by using the Go http package so that I can get the status code of any url . But after a bit of digging I checked to see why the request was taking long and I discovered that the URL keeps redirecting until I get status 200 OK.

I want to manage to get the first response from the web server. I don't want to get always 200 OK, whatever it gives me I want to take it. What should I do?

Example:
https://apple.com responded 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY when I used cURL to get the code.
That's the response I want, not a redirect to 200.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297520/how-can-i-make-the-go-http-client-not-follow-redirects-automatically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35089052/how-to-get-the-redirect-url-instead-of-page-content-in-golang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`http.Client`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/client.go) offers a possibility to control that via the `CheckRedirect` member.

From the link above:

```
// CheckRedirect specifies the policy for handling redirects.
// If CheckRedirect is not nil, the client calls it before
// following an HTTP redirect. The arguments req and via are
// the upcoming request and the requests made already, oldest
// first. If CheckRedirect returns an error, the Client's Get
// method returns both the previous Response and
// CheckRedirect's error (wrapped in a url.Error) instead of
// issuing the Request req.
//
// If CheckRedirect is nil, the Client uses its default policy,
// which is to stop after 10 consecutive requests.
ct func(req *Request, via []*Request) error
```

<sub>Disclaimer: Not tested.</sub>